# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar una propiedad de un objeto?

Tags: php

estoy intentando eliminar la propiedad de un objeto.
En este caso tengo una clase con las siguientes propiedades : id y nombre.
Necesito eliminar la propiedad nombre y evitar que se elimine la propiedad id.
He intentando eliminando la propiedad con unset,de tal forma que quedase algo así:

```
    <?php
require_once("Articulo.php");

$articulo1 = new Articulo(1,'Tijeras');
$articulo1->MostrarArticulo();
$articulo2 = clone $articulo1;
echo '<br>';
unset($nombre['nombre']);
$articulo2->MostrarArticulo();
?>
```

pero no hace ningún efecto, aparte no sé como evitar que se elimine la propiedad id.

En la clase Articulo tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
class Articulo{
private $id,$nombre;
function __construct($id,$nombre){
    if(isset($id,$nombre)){
    $this->id=$id;
    $this->nombre=$nombre;
    }
    else{
        echo "Variables NO definidas";
    }
}
function __clone(){
    $this->id++;
    
}
public function __get( string $var )
{
        return $this->$var;
}
public function __set( string $var, $val )
{
    $this->$var = $val;
}
public function MostrarArticulo(){
    echo "$this->id - $this->nombre";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Me dice que la variable nombre no está definida

Comment: He editado con más información

Comment: No se puede acceder al ser privada la propiedad

Comment: No me deja eliminarla

Comment: Pues create una función publica que haga eso

Comment: `public function borraNombre() { unset($this->nombre); }` y la ejecutas así: `$articulo2->borraNombre();`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias aquello me funcionó! y como puedo evitar que se elimine la propiedad id?

Comment: usando la funcion borraNombre() no se borra la propiedad id, no?  no se lo estamos diciendo

Comment: Tienes razón, muchísimas gracias y disculpa!

Comment: de nada, me alegro que te hay a funcionado, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes borrar un `atributo` de un `objeto`  lo que puesdes hacer es borrar su `valor` para ello

```
Articulo->__set("nombre","");
```

Para verficar

```
Articulo->MostrarArticulo();
```

Salida

```
"0001 -"
```